# Remove spaces between links from html table if links removed

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

I have below table in my jsp with links coming dynamically on page load using java arraylist

```
<%ArrayList<String> display  = ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("links");       %>
<table border="0" width="100%" style ="">
    <tr></tr>
    <td width="20%"></td>
    <table border="0" width ="50%" id="LinkDisplay">
        <div id="LinkDisplay">
            <%if(display!=null){
            for(int p=0;p<display.size();p++){%>
            <tr><td width="42%">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="javascript:removeLink('<%=display.get(p)%>')"><%=display.get(p)%></a><br></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <% } }%>
        </div>
    </table>
    <td></td>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

When I click on link, it remove and hide the link calling removeLink javascript function

```
$('#LinkDisplay a').click(function() { 
    var $this = $(this);         
    $this.remove();
}
```

But when link remove, it leaves the spaces between links. How to remove that space, when link clicked. I tried to hide even tried to remove the empty td element (without link text) but it does not help..
Page with all the links look as below :-

[image]

after clicking on links it leaves the spaces as below :-

[image]

Also if there are more than 10 links I want to add scroll bars, can we do that on table.
If table is not the right way to do all this, is there any other easy way?

Comment: Note your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `div` as a child of a `table`

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid. Anyway in CSS4, this should be possible: `tr:not(:has(li > a)) {display: none;}`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The use of `table` can be ommitted here, this can be simply ahieved with `divs` instead of `tr`, you can then easily manage the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the complete `<TR>`, `.closest()` can be used to traverse up to `<TR>` then remove it.

```
$('#LinkDisplay a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only removing the `a` element, you need to remove the whole `tr`:

```
$('#LinkDisplay a').click(function() { 
    var $this = $(this);         
    $this.parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Or even better `$this.parent("#LinkDisplay tr").remove();`.

**Note:**

- You can't use the same `id="LinkDisplay"` for more than one element, you used it for `table` and `div` here.
- Your HTML is invalid you can't have a `div` as immediate child of a `table`, it needs to be fixed.

And yes you can do this without a `table`, just use a `div` for each link, they will be displayed as `block` by default and use `margin` with your `div` instead of a `td` with `&nbsp;` as content, this way you can better manage the layout.